# How can I make the NPC move only vertical and horizontal and not diagonal with Vector2/3.MoveTowards and how can I make the NPC move only by tile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

So I was trying to make a game just for fun and to learn for future use. So I encountered this problem in making the enemy NPC. I want it to follow me or chase me but I want the NPC to only move horizontal and vertical and I want the NPC to move per tile as well just like my Player.

Here's the video of how it looks
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CB_vdt1Z3nA

and here's the NPC script

```
public class ChaseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private GameObject player;
    private Transform player_transform;


    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    }


    void Update()
    {
        player_transform = player.GetComponent<Transform>();
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player_transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Here's my player controller

```
public void InputMove()
    {
        if (!isMoving)
        {
            input.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            input.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            if (input.x != 0) input.y = 0;

            if (input != Vector2.zero)
            {
                playerAnimation.SetParameterValue(animator);

                var movePos = transform.position;
                movePos.x += input.x;
                movePos.y += input.y;
                FacingForward.transform.position = movePos;

                if (IsWalkable(movePos))
                    StartCoroutine(Move(movePos));
            }
            playerAnimation.SetParameterValueisMoving(animator);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            moveSpeed = 6f;
            animator.speed = 1.5f;
        }

        else
        {
            moveSpeed = 4f;
            animator.speed = 1f;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Move(Vector3 movePos)
    {
        isMoving = true;
        while ((movePos - transform.position).sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, movePos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
        transform.position = movePos;
        isMoving = false;
    }

    private bool IsWalkable(Vector3 movePos)
    {
        if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(movePos, 0.1f, SolidObjectLayer | NPC) != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

What I did to my Player to move per tile is I just add 1 to transform so It'll be a constant movement but I don't know how to apply it on the NPC with the Vector3.MoveTowards but if it's not possible to do then it's fine

Comment: Could you please include your player's movement script as well?

Comment: Okay just a moment

Comment: Okay I added it.

Comment: Maybe you could make the NPC mimic the player's movement. I recommend reading on the Command pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: That could be a good Idea. I will try it.

Comment: I think that the command pattern might be out of the scope of the question

Answer (score 0):

Check if this could work (you can adapt it to your 2D case)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ChaseOrthoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private GameObject player;
    private Transform player_transform;
    bool isMoving = false;

void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    player_transform = player.GetComponent<Transform>();
    transform.LookAt(player_transform.position);
}

void Update()
{
    if (transform.InverseTransformPoint(player_transform.position).z > 0) {
        transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        isMoving = true;
    } else {
        if (isMoving) {
            float angle = Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, player_transform.position - transform.position);
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Mathf.Sign(angle) * 90);
            isMoving = false;
        } else if (transform.InverseTransformPoint(player_transform.position).z <= 0) { //player is back
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 180);
        }
    }
}
}
```

note that the `player_transform = player.GetComponent<Transform>();` is moved to the `Start()`. Usually you dont want `GetComponents` in an update as you need to get it only once. ALso its much cleaner to have a `public GameObject player;` variable in the script and attach the reference in the editor that the         `player = GameObject.Find("Player");`. Usually you dont want scene elements found by a hardcoded magic value in your code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It was glitching

Comment: I dont know the axis of yout elements in your scene. The example is for 2 cubes in a new 3D project to achieve the movement as you want it the horizontal plane. You can take that as a reference to adapt it to your specific case

Comment: You can check with 2 cubes, name 1 "Player" and move it in the scene to check the orthogonal follow